# Finding the lowest number in an array but skipping zero

Tags: php

Can someone help me re-write this:

```
 public function allOutOfStockShows()
 {

    $out_of_stock_shows = 999;

    foreach ($this->variants as $variant){

        if (!$variant->out_of_stock_shows) { continue; }

        if ($variant->out_of_stock_shows < $out_of_stock_shows) { $out_of_stock_shows = $variant->out_of_stock_shows; }

    };

    if ($out_of_stock_shows == 999) { return 'Out Of Stock'; }

    return config('site.out_of_stock_shows')[$out_of_stock_shows]; // eg '2-3 days','3-5 days'
 }
```

The values for the (integer) $variant->out_of_stock_shows can range from 0-12 so I start the 'highest' number as being a number I plucked out of the air - 999 - and then I shoot for a lower value as you can see. It works but feels wrong, how should I be approaching this?

Comment: Why not simply use the sort() function? It would sort your values from smallest to largest. All you'd have to do then would be to grab the first

Comment: The only reason I didn't think of that is because my brain isn't being helpful today. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you convert to array and use [min()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) function;

```
$out_of_stock_shows = array_map( 
    function( $item ) { 
        return $item->out_of_stock_shows; 
    }, $this->variants );

$out_of_stock_shows = min( array_filter( $out_of_stock_shows ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks - using laravel's collections I remove all "0" elements, sorted the array and looked at what is at the top of the array:

```
 public function allOutOfStockShows()
 {
    $variants = $this->variants->reject(function ($variant){

        return $variant->out_of_stock_shows === 0;

    })->sortBy('out_of_stock_shows');

    if (isset($variants->first()->out_of_stock_shows)) {

        return config('site.out_of_stock_shows')[$variants->first()->out_of_stock_shows];

    }

    return "Out Of Stock";

 }
```